# How do developers manage application size with external packages?

Tags: python

In my ad-hoc education, i think i might have missed this concept. Say i wanted to distribute this app:

```
from very_large_external_package.large_module import HelloWorld

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HelloWorld().run()
```

The `.py` file is very small and the compiled `.pyc` version is even smaller; however, if i wanted to distribute my application, say as an executable, i would need to include `very_large_external_package`, or  `large_module` at the very least.

I've looked at [Snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/) as being a possible solution for my real-world application. It returned many dependencies of dependencies--meaning that i would need to go through each of them and start chopping otherwise very good code, which then gave me the feeling that i was going about this the wrong way.

How do python developers manage application size with imports?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what's your real problem? Are you running your applicaion on embedded devices? otherwise application size should not be a problem.

Comment: @glasslion: I'm using [kivy](http://kivy.org/#home) to design a variety of mobile apps for Andriod/iOS. I noticed that the HelloWorld app is ~6.5Mb compressed and suspect that at least some of that is pork from the auto-kivy-packaging method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options:

1. Don't worry about it. Simply require that `very_large_external_package` be installed to use your application. This is very common.  ([SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/), NumPy, Matplotlib, etc. also PyQt, are not small, and very often requied. I'm sure others could provide many more examples of this.)
2. Don't worry about it. Use something like [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) and simply deal with the large dependency-free binaries it generates.

It just really isn't reasonable (or maintainable) to go hacking out parts of 3rd party libraries to use in your application. (Unless you're talking about a *very* small, isolated piece, which is probably not the case.)

Comment: This is indeed surprising. Even when speculate on possible exploits from unused code? Does that factor in?

Comment: Fair enough. There really is no "magic" package? Is it because such a feat would be too difficult, or mathematically impossible? How would i Google this (can't find English terms)?

Comment: "magic" package to do what? Include only parts of 3rd party libs that are used?

Comment: Yes. My original thought was that `from this import that` was used to somehow compile `that`'s bytecode in with the importing module's bytecode--as opposed to `import this; this.that()`. I now know that my understanding was wrong; but is it really *that* far off from reality, or am i being naive?